# Maven dependency resolution fails because properties are not substituted

Tags: maven-3

We've been working on a maven (3.0.5) project for a couple of months now, and suddenly we're getting this error when establishing new dev environments (without a local maven repository):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project [100's of dependencies truncated]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:${httpcomponents.version}: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:pom:${httpcomponents.version} from/to nexus (http://bob.premitech.net:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): Illegal character in path at index 96: http://bob.premitech.net:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/${httpcomponents.version}/httpclient-${httpcomponents.version}.pom -> [Help 1]
```

I'm using a multi-module project, and the obvious thing you might think is wrong is that ${httpcomponents.version} isn't defined. Except it is defined as 4.2.5 in the parent pom. Even wierder, hardcoding the version instead of using the property does not change the error message.

I've even tried removing the http components dependency entirely. This also does nothing. The only thing that does work is manually copying the correct dependency into the local maven repository (.m2), which completely defeats the purpose of using maven in the first place.

Does anybody have the slightest idea what could be wrong here? Is there some kind of caching mechanism I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, even hard-coding the version in your POM still giving you such error, it seems to me that the "incorrect" version is coming from other dependencies transitively.  IIRC, place holders of dependencies are not replaced in Maven.

For example, your `foo` project is depending on your own `bar-framework`, both `foo` and `bar-framework` is depending on `httpcomponent`.  In `bar-framework` you are also using property place holder for the version.  In such case , if you built `bar-framework` in that new machine with problem, for which the `bar-framework` POM contains the un-substituted property of `httpcomponent` version.  Then even your `foo` project is correct, Maven will still need to resolve the incorrect httpcomponent because of transitive dependency.

Try to do `mvn dependency:tree` to see how you are getting the dependency in your project.  This may give some hints.

Comment: Glad to know the answer is helping  ;)